# Different way of calling a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hey I was learning Node as part of course where they made some variable equal to a function

Something like this

```
const authCheck = (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.user) {
        next()
    } else {
        res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/")
    }

}
```

and then they called it in a middleware

```
router.post("/", authCheck, (req, res) =>  {
```

Now, I have usually seen people calling a function like this `authCheck()` 
While that works, I wanted to comprehend the difference between both of them

Comment: `authCheck()` would call the function, (with no arguments, by the way) ... `authCheck` passes the function as an argument to `router.post` in your example - and something in `router.post` *may* call `authCheck` if required

Comment: *Now, I have usually seen people calling a function like this authCheck()* - consider providing the example where you saw this. This would be incorrect and result in error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`router.post("/", authCheck, (req, res) =>  {` This line does not actually call the function. It passed the function as a variable into the `router.post()` function.

That router function will then in time call authCheck, once a request arrives at the router function.

So you're correct that functions gets called by writing `()` behind the function name.
Remember that functions are so called 'first-class', meaning they can be used as parameters, passed around, anything you can do with a variable.

If you would write `router.post("/", authCheck(), (req, res) =>  {`, instead of passing the authCheck function into the router, you would immediately call authCheck and pass the return of authCheck into router.post() instead.

Comment: Shilly firstly thanks a lot for answering, just to summarise, if we pass say some function as a parameter `function something (authCheck(), somethingElse)`, then return of `authCheck()` will be the return of `something` and `somethingElse` would never been executed. Hence whenever we are passing function as a parameter we should always use 'authCheck`?

Comment: Euh? I don't get what you mean. Any function can be passed. authCheck is just the function that gets passed in this example. If you have `something( authCheck(), somethingElse )`, then the function something will be called. It takes two parameters. The second parameter is the variable somethingElse. The first parameter will be whatever authCheck returns. I expect authCheck to return like an object containing user credentials.

Comment: That returned object will then be the first parameters used inside `something()`. If somethingElse is also a function, it will depend completely on how something() is written to determine when to either use the object returned from calling authCheck() at the start, or when to call somethingElse(). The clue of everything is, any function only gets called once they have the `()` behind them.